# Creating an email address for my url

Tags: email, web, smtp

I just purchased a url from Godaddy, but looks like I have to pay to create any email addresses for it. Is there any otherway to not go through go daddy and just create an email address and host it on my own computer? I'm a programmer, but not familiar with email setup for websites.

Answer (score 0):

No you need to have a good hosting account that can help you create unlimited few emails.if you don't much money you can search for cheap or free hosting services that can host your url/website